# Composer is pulling in .git folder and treating it as a subproject

Tags: git, composer-php, gitlab-ee

I made a project hosted in a private Gitlab EE instance on my server with `"type": "library"`, and in my application, `require`d it as usual and also added a "repository" entry

```
{
    "type": "vcs",
    "url": "https://my.gitlab.install.com/repo-name/package-name.git"
}
```

Composer pulls the package in, but it also includes the `.git` folder causing Git to see it as a subproject.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have `vendor` directory in `.gitignore` of your project?

Comment: We're versioning the vendor directory in the application. And yes, in the package, `vendor` is ignored.

Comment: This is what you missed - you should exclude `vendor` from VCS in your application and use `composer.lock` to lock dependencies on specified version.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not an option at the moment. And, it also doesn't address the issue. The main issue is that my package's .git folder is getting pulled in through composer, while other package's .git aren't.